# Install python2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu

How can I install python2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 and make the system's default python the python I installed?

How can I install packages like numpy, scipy and so on in the python I installed? I don't know how to set these settings.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 already comes with Python 2.7...

Comment: `pip install python-scipy python-numpy`, etc.?

Comment: Maybe [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) is a good choice for you?

Comment: Python 2.7 is built-in. Just need to install `sudo apt-get install python-pip` and then `pip install numpy` etc

Comment: I want to install python by building from source but don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As Selcuk and warmoverflow said, both versions of python , python 2.x and 3.x comes already installed on ubuntu. However if you want to upgrade your python version, say python 2.7.6 to python 2.7.11 or so, you can upgrade it by downloading the latest version and building it from source.

Here is a good tutorial for that : [Tutorial 1](http://mbless.de/blog/2016/01/09/upgrade-to-python-2711-on-ubuntu-1404-lts.html)   [Tutorial 2](https://askubuntu.com/a/488502/431305)

You can also search on internet for the same.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it